# Let p be a prime number greater than or equal to 3. Show that if p ≡ 1 (mod 3), then p ≡ 1 (mod 6).

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I'm not sure how p being a prime number and greater than or equal to three plays into the proof.

Comment: Hint: $ $ if $\,1+3k\,$ is a prime $> 2$ then it is odd, so  $k$ must be $\ldots$ (what parity?) $\ \ $

Comment: Couldn't k be many different numbers? it could be 2, 4, 6. I know this satisfies both conditions, but I'm not sure how to right it down as a proof.

Comment: $k$ is either even or odd. Only one choice makes $1+3k$ odd.

Comment: Clearly $p\neq 3$, so $p>3$. Thought it would be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

If $p\equiv1\pmod3$, then $p\equiv1\pmod6$ or $p\equiv4\pmod6$.

But $p\equiv4\pmod6$ won't work, because that would mean $2\mid p$,

($6\mid p-4\implies 2\mid p-4\implies 2\mid p$),

so we're done.

Answer (score 0):

If is a prime then it can’t be multiple of 2. Or even. Given that remainder is 1 when dividing by 3, then quotient is even. Hope this helps.